# redirect all traffic coming from www.example.com to specific page in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect all incoming traffic from `http://www.example.com` to 
`http://www.mysite.com/badreferer.aspx?bad=true`.

I am working on IIS7 and asp.net 4.0 and c#.

Is there any way I can do configuration in IIS7?

```
<rule name="bad referer" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="(.*)example.com(.*)" /> 
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="(.*)example2.com(.*)" />                        
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/badreferer.aspx?bad=true" appendQueryString="false" />          
</rule>
```

This rule creates error `The webpage at http://www.mysite.com/badreferer.aspx?bad=true has resulted in too many redirects`.

Comment: I am surprised this rule doesn't work as expected. Can you try using the [`failed request tracing tool`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)?

Comment: rule worked but it is going in infinite loop. I do not know why?

Comment: Can you post somewhere the result you get with the failed request tracing tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Response.PermanentRedirect for that. For more information please go through following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx

Comment: is there any way i can change at one place and boom. I do not want to go through each and every page.

Comment: I think you can write that in begin request event of global.asax. It will call for every request.

Comment: i would like to do without changing any code and upload a new dll for application. Is there anyway i can just do it from IIS?